# Jquery resizable and draggable together doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Now i know there have been a lot of question about this, but i didn't find people having same issues as i do, so let's get to the point.

So jquery ui resizable function sets my `<img />` element `dimensions` to `0px` i even tried to set my own `width` and `height`. I've already tried removing it and after that everything looks just fine even `draggable` works fine.

So what could be causing this?

Here is Jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/SY9yq/3/

And code itself:

```
#test{
    width:90%;
    height:500px;
}
.container{
    display:inline-block;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
    border:1px solid black;
}​
$(document).ready(function(){
    callFunctionOne();

    function callFunctionOne(){
        elements = buildElements();
        $("#test").append(elements);
    }

    function buildElements(){
        return $("<div>")
            .addClass("container")
            .draggable()
            .append(
                $("<img />")
                    .addClass("image")
                    .attr("src", "http://blog.stackoverflow.com/audio/stackoverflow-300.png")
                    //if i delete this everything will work
                    .resizable()
                    //but if i keep it it sets image dimensions to 0px                
            );                      


    }
});
```

Btw it was really quick example of my actual script so it's a bit messy :P So don't blame me lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the image is loaded before calling `.resizable()` on it.

Fixed jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VKe5h/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    callFunctionOne();

    function callFunctionOne() {
        elements = buildElements();
        $("#test").append(elements);
    }

    function buildElements() {
        return $("<div>")
            .addClass("container")
            .draggable().append(
                $('<img class="resizable" />')
                .addClass("image")
                .attr("src", "http://blog.stackoverflow.com/audio/stackoverflow-300.png")
                .load(function() {
                    $(this).resizable();
                })
            );
    }
});​
```